# AWS API Gateway Custom Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I am trying to map my api to custom domain. Let's say I have a website hosted through route 53 (example.com ), then I want my the api to be at api.example.com. So, I am following this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html), I did everything as it said. But, when I do https://api.example.com/apiresource ,it says cannot resolve DNS. So, I am not sure if I have to setup another hosted zone for api.example.com and create NS record set ? The documentation doesn't say about it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Including [this part](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/images/api-gateway-custom-domain-dns-alias-set.png) in Route 53?  Carefully review your configuration there, for any errors. A common error is typing `api.example.com` instead of just typing `api` in the box at the top (`.example.com` is implied).  Obviously, the `djozxyqkexample.cloudfront.net` value will be the one you got from API Gateway, not the one in the example.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating host zone for api.example.com.

Comment: How long you had to wait for DNS records to update? I am waiting for 2 hours already :(

Comment: Cannot recall exactly, it's been a while. May be half a day.